# Making new object from custom class- name using a variable value?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I am making a LIST to organize and manipulate arrays that represent lines off a spreadsheet.  I've created a custom class for the arrays, and will call them out as objects.

My question is, can I use a value stored in a variable as the name of the object?  If so, what would the syntax look like?

```
dim FileName as String
FileName = 123456.csv

Public Class List_Array
    public variable1 as string
    public variable2 as string
    public variable3 as string
    public variable4 as string
    End Class

dim File_Name as List_Array = NEW List_Array
```

This is the coding as I understand it, but I keep thinking this will only create one Object over and over again with the same name as the string variable.

If not, how can I differentiate the different objects as I call them?  There will be thousands of objects to reference, so using an unnamed object will not work so well.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store a list of named objects, what you need is a [`Dictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx).  `Dictionary` objects store a list of key/value pairs.  In this case, the "key" is the name that you want to assign to the object, and the value is the reference to the object itself.  It's a generic class, which means when you use the `Dictionary` type, you must specify the types that you want it to use for it's keys and values.  For instance `Dictionary(Of String, MyClass)` will create a list that uses `String` objects for its keys and `MyClass` objects for its values.

Here's an example of how you could use a dictionary to store a list of people with their ages:

```
Dim d As New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)()
d("Bob") = 30
d("Mary") = 42
```

Then, when you want to read a value, you can do it like this:

```
Dim age As Integer = d("Bob")
```

The `Dictionary` will only allow one item per key.  It uses a hash table to index the values by their keys, so it's very fast get any item by its key.

### Edit

Based on your comments below, here's a more pertinent example to show what I mean.  Let's say you have a CSV file containing a list of people.  So you create a class that stores all of the information about one person (one line of the CSV file), like this:

```
Public Class Person
    Public Property Id As String
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Title As String
End Class
```

Then, you create a method which parses a single line from the CSV file and returns all of the fields from that line as an array of strings, like this:

```
Public Function ParseCsvLine(line As String) As String()
    ' ...
End Function
```

Then, you could load all of the people into a list, like this:

```
Dim persons As New List(Of Person)()
For Each line As String In File.ReadAllLines("People.csv")
    Dim fields() As String = ParseCsvLine(line)        
    Dim person As New Person()
    person.Id = fields(0)
    person.Name = fields(1)
    person.Title = fields(2)
    persons.Add(person)
Next
```

Now you have all of the `Person` objects loaded into one list.  The problem is, though, that the list is not indexed.  If, for instance, you needed to find the person with an ID of `100`, you'd need to loop through all of the `Person` objects in the list until you found one with that value in it's `Id` property.  If you want to index them by ID so that you can find them more easily/quickly, you can use a `Dictionary`, like this:

```
Dim persons As New Dictionary(Of String, Person)()
For Each line As String In File.ReadAllLines("People.csv")
    Dim fields() As String = ParseCsvLine(line)        
    Dim person As New Person()
    person.Id = fields(0)
    person.Name = fields(1)
    person.Title = fields(2)
    persons(person.Id) = person
Next
```

Then, when you need to get a person from the dictionary, you can easily access it by ID, like this:

```
Dim person100 As Person = persons("100")
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  My issue comes in that each object from the class has upwards of 20 variables attached to it, so I don't think Dictionary would be able to help.  Each object is a 20 element array, and I am uncertain how to name the objects, and then be able to reference those objects efficiently using the LIST function.

Comment: That's fine.  You can still use that class as the value type for the dictionary.  The dictionary doesn't care what type is used for the value.  It could be any type of any complexity.  Or are you saying that you don't want it to have that many variables in it?

Comment: I have to manipulate and sort the values once they are stored.  I thought that required the object/arrays be stored in a LIST, with the object names being the item I needed to be able to sort on.

Comment: You've totally lost me.  I really don't know what you are trying to accomplish.  Yes.  It's true, you need a list, of some sort, of items before you can sort said list, but I'm not sure how that has anything to do with what we are talking about.  If you have all of the objects stored in the dictionary, you can query it to build a list and sort it any time you want.  You can have the same objects referenced by a hundred different dictionaries and a hundred different lists and a hundred different controls and a hundred different properties and variables all at the same time.

Comment: My question was, can I use the value inside of a variable to name an object?  If so, what is the syntax for that declaration?

Comment: What do you mean by "name"?  As I've already said, you can add the object to a dictionary and use that variable as the value for the key.  That *names* the object in the sense that you have uniquely identified it with that value and you can now retrieve it at any point by that value.  I'm not sure what else you might mean by "name"...

Comment: When I create the 10,000 objects, I do not want to have to manually assign an identifier to each one.

Comment: Before using the dictionary, every object has to be declared.  
Every object has to be given a distinct name.  
Dim XXXX as NEW_ARRAY is named XXXX.  
Since I will have 10,000 objects, I would like to automate the creation of those objects using a loop.  
But, if the object creation loop uses the same name over and over again, I understand that the object would overwrite itself 9999 times.  There would only be one instance of that object.  
I would like to use the value of a variable as that distinct name. 
However, I think that typing in a name of a variable in the name position while ...

Comment: ...declaring the object would only overwrite the first object over and over again.  
Is there a specific syntax that puts the VALUE of a previously declared variable as the name of an object?  
So, XXXX= 1111
Dim "XXXX" as NEW_ARRAY would be named 1111
Then XXXX=2222
Dim "XXXX" as NEW_ARRAY would be named 2222
Then XXXX=3333
Dim "XXXX" as NEW_ARRAY would be named 3333.

Comment: The variable name is not the name of the object.  It's just a handle that you use to refer to the object.  If I say `Dim x As New MyClass` and then I say `Dim y As MyClass = x`, I now have two variables (`x` and `y`) but they both point to the exact same object.  If I change the value of one of it's properties via `x`, such as `x.variable1 = "test"`, then it also changes it for `y`.  `y` doesn't change because the value gets copied to both.  `y` changes because both `x` and `y` are pointing to the same memory location.  They are two different "names" for the same exact object.

Comment: Object's don't have names.  Variables have names, but variables aren't objects, they are just variables.  By default, variables equal `Nothing` (null) which means they are not currently pointing at any object at all.

Comment: If you want 10000 objects, then you surely don't want to dynamically generate 10000 unique string names for them.  Surely you just want to index them by number (e.g. object #1, object #2, object #3, ...)  That's precisely what a list or an array is.  It's a list of any number of objects ordered by index.  So `myList(0)` is the first object, `myList(1)` is the second object, etc.  It sounds like that's all you are asking for.

Comment: I do not want to use multiple variables to create new class instances.  I want to use ONE variable to name the class instances. 
How do I use a VALUE in a variable to name the object/each individual class instance?

How do I code using the value in variable i as the name in each instance of the class?  
So, when i = 1, 
Everything I have seen so far looks like I have to manually declare all 10,000 class instances.  I DO want to programmatically create each one.  If that means making a directory with other values, that's fine.  But I do not want to manually create each class instance.

Comment: You are describing a list.  You create one list object which holds all of those other objects.  Then you use `i` as the index of the object in the list.  So when `i = 1`, that means you use the object that is item #1 in the list.

Comment: Let me reiterate.  Objects (class-instances) do not have names.  They just don't.  If you think they do, you are misunderstanding something.

Comment: Logic I am trying to program<br/>
Read single line of info from csv file<br/>
Place data from csv file into temp array<br/>
Assign value to variable i (exa i = 12345)<br/>
Create class instance named after value of i (object named 12345)<br/>
Loop back,  
read single line of data from csv file  
Overwrite data in temp array using info from new line  
Reassign value of variable i (exa i = 23456)<br/>
Create new instance of class named VALUE of i (object named 23456)<br/>
Continue looping back until info from all lines are in instances.<br/>  
If i = index, that is ok.<br/>

Comment: Are the values of `i` consecutive?  Do they start a 1 or 0?

Comment: If they are consecutive, use a `List(Of T)` or an array.  If they are not consecutive, use a `Dictionary(Of Integer, T)`.  (Where `T` is the class of your object that stores the data from each line of the CSV file.

Comment: "Objects (class-instances) do not have names. They just don't. If you think they do, you are misunderstanding something."  <br>
Then how do I create a new instance of a class without having a handle on it?  Every example I have seen is on this line  <br>
Dim C As Class1  <br>
Set C = New Class1  <br>

Comment: In that example, `C` is not the name of the object.  It's the name of a variable that is pointing to (referencing) the object.  As I said before, you could have many variables, all with different names, all pointing at the same object.  Those aren't the names of the object itself, just the names of the variables by which you reference them.  The object, on it's own, doesn't actually have a name.  You can create an object without ever referencing it with any variable.

Comment: For instance, in the line `Dim x As Integer = (New Date(0)).DayOfYear`, it creates a new `Date` object and then reads the `DayOfYear` property of that object.  The value of that property is then stored in the `x` integer, but there is never a named variable that ever points to that `Date` object.

Comment: Often, when you are working with lists, you don't ever create a named variable for each object either.  For instance, if I created a list like `Dim myList As New List(Of FileStream)`, I could then add an *"unnamed"* object to it like this: `myList.Add(New FileStream("Test.txt", FileMode.Open))`.  That just created a new `FileStream` object and added it to the list.  I never created a `FileStream` variable by any particular name to point to that `FileStream` object.  I just created it and added it directly to that list.

Comment: Or you often need to reference many different objects with the same variable.  For instance, you may have a variable like `Dim x As FileStream` and then inside a loop, you may set `x = New FileStream(...)` and then do something with it, like you might, later in that loop, add it to a list like `myList.Add(x)`.  That doesn't mean that all of those `FileStream` objects that you created are all named `x`.  The `x` variable only references the first one until it is set to reference the second one.  It only references one at a time.  Those `FileStream` objects aren't *named* anything.

Comment: And you would be able to refer to that new object by creating a list/dictionary that captures the relevant data for those new filestream objects.  
And then there was light!   
Thank you for your patience!  I think I get it now!

Comment: Yay!  I knew you'd get it eventually :)  I just finished adding a couple of new examples to my answer which hopefully demonstrate that more clearly.