# When declaring an object, how to use variable as the name?

Tags: vb.net

Can I use the value inside of a variable to name an object? If so, what is the syntax for that declaration? 
Every object has to be given a distinct name. Dim XXXX as NEW_ARRAY is named XXXX. Since I will have 10,000 objects, I would like to automate the creation of those objects using a loop. But, if the object creation loop uses the same name over and over again, I understand that the object would overwrite itself 9999 times. There would only be one instance of that object.

I would like to use the value of a variable as that distinct name. However, I think that typing in a name of a variable in the name position while declaring the object would only overwrite the first object over and over again. 
Is there a specific syntax that puts the VALUE of a previously declared variable as the name of an object? 
So, XXXX= 1111 
Dim "XXXX" as NEW_ARRAY would be named 1111 
Then XXXX=2222 
Dim "XXXX" as NEW_ARRAY would be named 2222 
Then XXXX=3333 
Dim "XXXX" as NEW_ARRAY would be named 3333.

Comment: if you tinkered with what you are trying you'd see where your assumptions are wrong.  If you have 10k things, you's store them in the array as `XXX(index) = 1111`.  the array would still be named XXX but the element at location `index` would **contain** the value 1111

Comment: I have a variable, XXXX that changes whenever a loop gets run.
I want to use the value of that variable as the name of an array.
Run a loop, the value of XXXX changes.  
Create ANOTHER array, named the most recent value of XXXX.  
I will end up with about 10,000 DIFFERENT arrays.  
There would be a separate array that tracks the different values of XXXX.

Comment: you cant name arrays (or anything) as values (`1` nor `1111`). further, variables have to be known at compile time, so you cant give one a name based on something that hasnt happened yet. (this is turning into an XY question) in order to keep track of things you could store the result in a List(Of T) so that the last one is the most recent and/or each of them could be any array.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Making new object from custom class- name using a variable value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22697576/making-new-object-from-custom-class-name-using-a-variable-value)

Answer (score 0):

**Object doesn't have name, variable has**. @StevenDoggart already elaborate about that [for you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22698005/2998271).

If the question was "*Can I use the value inside of a variable to name a new variable?*" Short answer is "no, you can't". There is no point to have such specific feature in .NET.

You can achieve *similar* behavior using dictionary, as suggested in many posts asking about dynamic variable name in .NET. You can see dictionary key as variable name, and dictionary value as variable value. As far as I can see, what you can do given such *dynamic variable name* feature exists in .NET, can be done equally well using dictionary.